Why doesn't mypy follow config in GitHub Actions?
If I run mypy locally it will only type check certain files because the pyproject.toml file has the following inclusion:
[tool.mypy]
files = [
    "python/project/file1.py",
    "python/project/file2.py"
]
strict = true

This is in a project with the following structure:
- root
  - pyproject.toml
  - python
    - project
      - file1.py
      - file2.py
      - other_files.py

My workflow looks roughly like this:
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4
    - name: Set up Rust
      uses: actions-rust-lang/setup-rust-toolchain@v1
    - name: Set up Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-python@v3
      with:
        python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install .[dev] -v
    - name: Test with pytest and display Coverage
      run: |
        coverage run -m --source=project pytest
        coverage report -m
    - name: MyPy type checking
      run: |
        mypy --config-file pyproject.toml  

But when it runs it doesn't just type check the specific files it also types all other files in the project and returns 1,000s of errors. Why?
